# Get matched word count from a variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I want to get the total count of `test` word in the `$channel` variable, but `$a` returns the same as `$channel`.

```
$channel = "test1 test2 test3 test4 testIgnore1 testIgnore2 testIgnore3"
$a = Select-String -InputObject $channel -Pattern "test"
```

What should be the exact solution here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$channel = "test1 test2 test3 test4 testIgnore1 testIgnore2 testIgnore3"
([regex]::Matches($channel, "test" )).count
```

Will give you the count of the matches: `7`

Answer (score 8):

Use the `-AllMatches` parameter switch to get all matches from `Select-String`:

```
$channel = "test1 test2 test3 test4 testIgnore1 testIgnore2 testIgnore3"
$a = Select-String -InputObject $channel -Pattern "test" -AllMatches
```

`$a` will contain a `MatchInfo` object. Count its `Matches`:

```
$a.Matches.Count
```